# How to compile multiple files in cobol online?

Tags: cobol

I am using www.compileonline.com.I wrote a program which reads from one file and writes the data in another file.In the online compiler there is only one tab called input.txt.how can I run this program  with two files using this online compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is one input file and one output file , it would perhaps be a bit silly to expect to allow a webpage to write a file to your machine in this way.

There is no indication at all that you can do this.

Go to https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/?source=navbar where you can download an up-to-date version of the same COBOL compiler (Open COBOL is now GnuCOBOL) and instal it on your machine and have as many input and output files as you like. There is also full and active support for your issues, however small, for the dowloaded GnuCOBOL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's supposed to be an online compilation system to make things easier for *simple* programs.

I think the idea is, if you want more complex stuff, you will get your *own* COBOL development system and use that.

But, if that's not an option for some reason, you have a couple of other possibilities, one fast and one slow.

The fast one is writing your code to detect some sort of marker in the input file and use that to separate the sorts of data coming in. For example, you may have one input file per `===`-separated section:

```
1 paxdiablo
2 jon skeet
3 someone else
===
banana 2
apple 2
orange 1
```

You would then have to code your application to allow for this.

The slow option is to use the [`Contact us`](http://www.compileonline.com/contact.php) link in the right side pane or at the bottom of the main page, to request multiple input files as a feature.